# How to display images dynamically in slider on clicking a particular image using angular js

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

we have a problem in displaying images in slider dynamically.i.e, when we click on a particular image in list it must be displayed in the slider.We are getting the images from a json file.The problem is the images are not getting displayed in slider,but the click functionality is working.Clicked image ids are shown in console too.
Here is the code:

```
enter code here
   JSON:
[{
"menuId": "01",
"menuItem": "manuchuriya",
"menuImage": "img/Categoryimages/manchuria.jpe",
"items": [{

    "id": "001",
    "itemName": "Noodles",
    "itemImage": "item_images/aloo_chaat.jpg",
    "price": "$30",
    "description": "Add water or veg stock.mix well and add let the sauce simmer for 1-2 minutes.add the cornflour paste to thicken the sauce.Thicken the sauceto your desired consistency.add vinegar, salt, sugar and the fried veg balls.serve veg manchurian garnished with spring onion greens."
}, 
{

    "id": "002",
    "itemName": "Noodles",
    "itemImage": "item_images/samosa.jpg",
    "price": "$20",
    "description": "Add water or veg stock.mix well and add let the sauce simmer for 1-2 minutes.add the cornflour paste to thicken the sauce.Thicken the sauceto your desired consistency.add vinegar, salt, sugar and the fried veg balls.serve veg manchurian garnished with spring onion greens."

}]
}, 

{
    "menuId": "02",
    "menuItem": "icecream",
    "menuImage": "img/Categoryimages/ice-cream.jpg",
    "items": [{
            "id": "001",
            "itemName": "salad",
            "itemImage": "item_images/fruit_juice.jpg",
            "price": "$40",
            "description":"Add ghee, salt and carom seeds in maida. Mix all ingredients. Cut paneer into small chunks.Peel potatoes and mash them Knead the dough until it becomes soft. Take little amount of dough and roll it."
    },
    {
            "id": "002",
            "itemName": "salad",
            "itemImage": "item_images/bevarages.jpg",
            "price": "$20",
            "description":"Add ghee, salt and carom seeds in maida. Mix all ingredients. Cut paneer into small chunks.Peel potatoes and mash them Knead the dough until it becomes soft. Take little amount of dough and roll it."
        }]

},
 {
    "menuId": "03",
    "menuItem": "franke",
    "menuImage": "img/Categoryimages/samosas.jpg",
    "items": [{
        "id": "001",
        "itemName": "salad",
        "itemImage": "item_images/frankie.jpg",
        "price": "$30",
        "description":"Add ghee, salt and carom seeds in maida. Mix all ingredients. Cut paneer into small chunks.Peel potatoes and mash them Knead the dough until it becomes soft. Take little amount of dough and roll it."
      }, 
       {
        "id": "002",
        "itemName": "salad",
        "itemImage": "item_images/aloo_chaat.jpg",
        "price": "$40",
        "description":"Add ghee, salt and carom seeds in maida. Mix all ingredients. Cut paneer into small chunks.Peel potatoes and mash them Knead the dough until it becomes soft. Take little amount of dough and roll it."
       }]
}]
```

Controller:

```
angular.module('starter')
.controller('menuitemCtrl', function ($scope,$state,$q,$stateParams,menuService) {
    console.log($stateParams.id);
    $scope.id = $stateParams.id;
var getMenuList = function(){
    menuService.getMenuListData()
    .then(function sucessCallback(response){
        $scope.menulists = response;
        console.log("menu");
        for(var i in $scope.menulists.items)
                {

                    if($scope.menulists[i].items[i].id === $scope.id)
                    {
                        $scope.SliderItem=$scope.menulists[i].items[i];
                        console.log(SliderItem);
                    }

                }   
         function errorCallback(error){
        return $q.reject(error);
    });         
};

getMenuList();
});
```

HTML Code:

```
<ion-view class="view-styles-item" style="margin-left: 24%">
<ion-content scroll="false">
  <ion-slides  options="options" slider="data.slider">
    <ion-slide-page ng-repeat="item in SliderItem.items">
      <div class="row">
      <img src="img/menuitem/{{item.itemImage}}" style="width: 52%;">
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <p>{{item.description}}</p>
        <p>{{item.price}}</p>
      </div>
    </ion-slide-page> 
  </ion-slides>
</ion-content>
```

Click event HTML Code:

```
    <ion-view class="view-styles-menu" >
  <ion-content >
    <div ng-repeat="item in SelectedMenu.items" >
    <div class="row menu-row">
   <div class="col">
   <!-- <a href="#/tab/home/item?id={{item.id}}">  -->
      <img src="/img/menuitem/{{item.itemImage}}" class="menu-img_styles" ng-click="goToMenuItem(item.id)">
   </div>
   <div class="col">
     {{item.itemName}}
   </div>
   <div class="col">
     {{item.price}}
   </div>
  </div>
    </div>
    <ion-nav-view name="tab-item"></ion-nav-view>
  </ion-content>
  <div class="divider"></div>
</ion-view>
```

Controller:

```
$scope.goToMenuItem = function(paramId){
     $state.go('tab.home.menu.item',{id:paramId});
   };
```

Comment: i think we need some more code...where is the click event in html which you mentioned in the description

Comment: I have attached the code please check it